# how to store custom collection in cache in admin grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, cache

My collection model is `testimonial/record`. In database table(`testimonial_record`) 2,00,000 records so it loads more how to decrease time to fetch collection data in grid.So I think I have to store collection in cache to display in grid.is this good approach ? if good approach how to store collection in cache.

How can use below cache function in collection grid ?

```
Mage::app()->saveCache($data, $this->_cacheId, array(self::CACHE_TAG), 604800);
```

my **Grid.php**

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
        {       $collection = Mage::getModel("testimonial/record")->getCollection();
                $this->setCollection($collection);
                return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cache one particular block in Magento. so, call your collection in the block and cache your block.

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->addData(array(
       'cache_lifetime' => 3600,
       'cache_tags'     => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG),
       'cache_key'      => $this->getProduct()->getId(),
    ));

}
```

For more reference follow below URL

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-block-caching/

Comment: I am not display thi collection data in frontend as block .this is for only backend data.I want to use in only backend so how can I ?